# Interrupting a while loop by a variable, then using vwait to wait for the loop to die. Not Working?

Tags: tcl, expect, interactive, tk-toolkit

I currently have a GUI, that after some automation (using expect) allows the user to interact with one of 10 telnet'ed connections. Interaction is done using the following loop:

```
#After selecting an item from the menu, this allows the user to interact with that process
proc processInteraction {whichVariable id id_list user_id} {
    if {$whichVariable == 1} {
        global firstDead
        set killInteract $firstDead
    } elseif {$whichVariable == 2} {
        global secondDead
        set killInteract $secondDead
    }
    global killed

    set totalOutput ""
    set outputText ""
    #set killInteract 0
    while {$killInteract == 0} {
        set initialTrue 0
        if {$whichVariable == 1} {
            global firstDead
            set killInteract $firstDead
        } elseif {$whichVariable == 2} {
            global secondDead
            set killInteract $secondDead
        }
        puts "$id: $killInteract"
        set spawn_id [lindex $id_list $id]
        global global_outfile

        interact  {
            -i $spawn_id
            eof {
                set outputText "\nProcess closed.\n"
                lset deadList $id 1
                puts $outputText
                #disable the button
                disableOption $id $numlcp
                break
            }

            -re (.+) {
                set outputText $interact_out(0,string)
                append totalOutput $outputText
                #-- never looks at the following string as a flag
                send_user -- $outputText
                #puts $killInteract
                continue
            }

            timeout 1 {
                puts "CONTINUE"
                continue
            }        
        }
    }
    puts "OUTSIDE"
    if {$killInteract} {
        puts "really killed in $id"
        set killed 1
    }
}
```

When a new process is selected, the previous should be killed. I previously had it where if a button is clicked, it just enters this loop again. Eventually I realized that the while loops were never quitting, and after 124 button presses, it crashes (stackoverflow =P). They aren't running in the background, but they are on the stack. So I needed a way to kill the loop in the `processInteraction` function when a new process is started. Here is my last attempt at a solution after many failures:

```
proc killInteractions {} {
    #global killed
    global killInteract
    global first
    global firstDead
    global secondDead
    global lastAssigned

    #First interaction
    if {$lastAssigned == 0} {
        set firstDead 0
        set secondDead 1
        set lastAssigned 1
        #firstDead was assigned last, kill the first process
    } elseif {$lastAssigned == 1} {
        set firstDead 1
        set secondDead 0
        set lastAssigned 2
        vwait killed
        #secondDead was assigned last, kill the second process
    } elseif {$lastAssigned == 2} {
        set secondDead 1
        set firstDead 0
        set lastAssigned 1
        vwait killed
    }

    return $lastAssigned
}
```

`killInteractions` is called when a button is pressed. The script hangs on `vwait`. I know the code seems a bit odd/wonky for handling processes with two variables, but this was a desperate last ditch effort to get this to work.

A dead signal is sent to the correct process (in the form of `secondDead` or `firstDead`). I have the timeout value set at 1 second for the interact, so that it is forced to keep checking if the `while` loop is true, even while the user is interacting with that telnet'ed session. Once the dead signal is sent, it waits for confirmation that the process has died (through `vwait`).

The issue is that once the signal is sent, the loop will never realize it should die unless it is given the context to check it. The loop needs to run until it is kicked out by `first` or `secondDead`. So there needs to be some form of wait before switching to the next process, allowing the loop in `processInteraction` of the previous process to have control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is the `global killed` line in killInteractions commented out?  Are you sure `killed` is getting set by processInteraction properly?

Comment: Doesn't vwait automatically look for the variable at the global level?had it in before and didn't work anyway.And yes,it seems that killed is properly getting changed in processInteraction.If it kicks out of the loop due killInteract being set,the if loop that sets killed is entered. I've seen this work a few times,since the 2nd process that I had clicked had a syntax error in it.As a result,that process immediately ended.The first process' while loop was entered back into, and it quit correctly,(since it was ordered to be killed by left its while loop prematurely do to the next button press)

Comment: The `vwait` command always resolves variable names with respect to the global namespace; if they don't have `::` in, they're global.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems extremely complicated to me. However, the key problem is that you are running inner event loops (the event loop code is pretty simple-minded, and so is predictably a problem) and building up the C stack with things that are stuck. You don't want that!

Let's start by identifying where those inner event loops are. Firstly, `vwait` is one of the canonical event loop commands; it runs an event loop until its variable is set (by an event script, presumably). However, it is not the only one. In particular, Expect's `interact` *also* runs an event loop. This means that everything can become nested and tangled and… well, [you don't want that](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255). (That page talks about [`update`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/update.htm), but it applies to all nested event looping.) Putting an event loop inside your own `while` is particularly likely to lead to debugging headaches.

The best route to fixing this is to rewrite the code to use continuation-passing style. Instead of writing code with nested event loops, you instead rearrange things so that you have pieces of code that are evaluated on events and which pass such state as is necessary between them *without* starting a nested event loop. (If you weren't using Expect and were using Tcl 8.6, I'd advise using [`coroutine`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/coroutine.htm) to do this, but I don't think that works with Expect currently and it does require a beta version of Tcl that isn't widely deployed yet.)

Alas, everything is made more complicated by the need to interact with the subprocesses. There's no way to interact in the background (nor does it really make that much sense). What you instead need to do is to use exactly one `interact` in your whole program and to have it switch between spawned connections. You do that by giving the `-i` option the name of a global variable which holds the current id to interact with, instead of the id directly. (This is an “indirect” spawn id.) I think that the easiest way of making this work is to have a “not connected to anything else” spawn id (e.g., you connect it to `cat >/dev/null` just to act as a do-nothing) that you make at the start of your script, and then swap in the real connection when it makes sense. The actual things that you currently use `interact` to watch out for are best done with `expect_background` (remember to use `expect_out` instead of `interact_out`).

Your code is rather too long for me to rewrite, but what you should do is to look very carefully at the logic of the `eof` clause of the `interact`; it needs to do more than it does at the moment. The code to kill from the GUI should be changed too; it should `send` a suitable EOF marker to the spawned process(es) to be killed and *not wait* for the death to be confirmed.